# Raster resampling using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, resampling

I have gridded raster files with 6 km resolution, and each cell has its own respective Snow Cover value. Now, I want to change the resolution of this raster to 500 m, and based on the 6 km pixel values assign new Snow Cover values to each pixel of 500 m resolution.

Which method in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 (interpolation or resampling technique) would best suit this kind of conversion and data?

Comment: You need much better model. I'd use cell elevations to assign 1, 0 to smaller cells , e.g. 72 highest cell will get value of 1 ( snow) if parent cell stores value of 50 %.

Comment: @ user2856, after the conversion to 500 m of the dataset mentioned in this question, it will be compared with the 500 m MODIS snow cover dataset and one other type of 500 m snow cover dataset. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: You want to resample using bilinear or cubic resampling. I will say that resampling from 6km to 500m is not supported from a process standpoint and statistical comparison, with native 500m data, will not be valid. You can do this to create a common mapping resolution but, for statistical comparison i would reccomend using a random point sample that is independent from any resolution.

Comment: @ Jeffrey Evans, with random point sampling, will the values assigned to the random point sample (i.e. using the "export multi values to point" tool in ArcGIS) of the courser raster and the values assigned to the random point sample of the finer resolution raster be comparable? This is what I understood from your comment that a random point sample is independent of resolution. Please correct me if I am wrong!